How do i integrate python script in a react-native app targeted for android
Guidance needed. I have a Python script that uses MediaPipe and OpenCV modules to map a 2D image of clothing on the person's body based on the extracted coordinates. This is done in real-time (tested on a webcam). I have a react-native-based app on the other side. I want to integrate this script in the app such that the script is run on the mobile camera and the same functionality is achieved within the app. Considering the real-time nature of this script, I have failed to find a solution yet.
Since, media pipe and OpenCV are Python-specific packages, bringing their functionality to an Android app has been challenging. I have tried using Google's media pipe repo for Android, however, it contains example apps which i have not been able to alter for my use case and opencv remains a challenge.
